# ¿Cómo separar palabras de una cadena sin que aparezcan con puntos, comas signos de interrogación, etc?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo el siguiente ejercicio:

Diseñar un programa que lea una cadena y un número entero N y diga cuántas palabras tienen una longitud de N caracteres.

Hay que tener en cuenta que por ejemplo en "María, quien tiene 12 hermanos. trabaja en Manizales!.", el 12 no se considera una palabra y que los signos de puntuación no cuentan para determinar la longitud de la palabra; por lo que María tiene 5 letras (no seis si se incluye la coma).

Esto es lo que llevo hasta ahora, no logro quitar signos de puntuación.

```
""" Este programa lee una cadena y un entero N y dice cuántas palabras tienen
    una longitud de N caracteres')
"""


cad = "María, quien tiene 12 hermanos. Trabaja en Manizales!."

while True:
    try:
        print("\nRecuerde que el número que va a ingresar debe ser positivo...")
        N = int(input("Ingrese el número de letras de la/s "
                  "palabras/s que quiere ver:   "))
        if type(N) == int and N > 0:
            break
    except ValueError:
        print("\nERROR\nPor favor solo ingrese números enteros positivos")

# Separa cada vez que encuentra un espacio en la cadena y lo agrega a una lista.
aux = cad.split()
# Almacenará en una lista las palabras que tengan N caracteres.
palabras_N = []

for palabra in aux:
    if len(palabra) == N:
        if palabra.isalpha():
            if palabra.isalpha():
                palabras_N.append(palabra)

if len(palabras_N) > 0:
    mas = "as" if len(palabras_N) > 1 else "a"
    print("\nHay %s palabr%s con la longitud de %s caracteres:" % (len(palabras_N), mas, N))

    for palabra in palabras_N:
        print("\nPalabra: %s" % palabra)

else:
    print("\nNo hay ninguna palabra con la longitud de %s caracteres" % N)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deberias recorrer cada palabra verificando que sean caracteres, este código te puede servir, como puedes ver modifique el bloque del for para recorrer cada palabra y almacenar solo los caracteres en la variable `nueva` luego se verifica que la longuitud de la palabra tenga la longuitud deseada para almacenarla.

```
for palabra in aux:
    nueva = ""
    for c in palabra:
        # Verificando que sean caracteres                                                                   
        if c.isalpha():
            nueva += c    
    if len(nueva) == N:
       palabras_N.append(nueva)

if len(palabras_N) > 0:
...
```

**Actualización 1**: almacena solo los caracteres en una nueva variable "nueva" y la agrega al vector "palabras_N" para que no se impriman los signos.

**Actualización 2**: elimación de variable innecesaria (cuenta).

Comment: Gracias, mmm ¿hay alguna manera de que dichos signos de puntuación etc, no se impriman en pantalla, solo se me pide la  que aparezca la palabra?

Comment: Mira la actualización, modifiqué el código.

Answer (score 2):

Podrías poner un string con todos los caracteres que quisieras quitar y luego los comparas con cada letra de tu palabra, si son iguales entonces eliminas dicho símbolo de la palabra. Yo lo hice remplazando tu for por lo siguiente y funcionó:

```
# String de los símbolos que se desean quitar (Agrega aquí todos los que consideres necesarios
a_quitar = "¡!,;.-_"

for palabra in aux:
    #quita los simbolos que no se desean en la palabra
    for letra in palabra:
        for char in a_quitar:
            if letra == char:
                palabra = palabra.replace(char,'')
    if len(palabra) == N:
        if palabra.isalpha():
            palabras_N.append(palabra)
```